# Getting 'Invalid envelope status' resending documents through Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I am re-sending documents via the API.  This has worked for a long time, and suddenly started getting these errors?  I can't figure out what is going on?  Does anyone have any ideas?

The actual envelope status is 'Waiting on Others', which of course is not in the list below, but we need to resend the envelope, because the user never got the email.  So how do I deal with this?

```
{ "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_INVALID_STATUS", 
  "message": "Invalid envelope status. Envelope status is not one of: Created, Sent, Delivered, Correct." }


EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new 
    EnvelopesApi(GetBasePath(myAccount.BaseUrl));
envelopesApi.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader(
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myHeader));
EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions options = new 
    EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions();
options.resendEnvelope = "true";
envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients(myAccount.AccountId,
    EnvelopeId, docuSignRecipients, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing what the `docusignRecipients` value is.

I suggest you first obtain the recipients object via [EnvelopeRecipients::list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list) and then use it in the call.

Also, at the API level, there is no envelope status of `Waiting on Others`. I suggest you also obtain the envelope status so you can see what is going on.

I'm sorry to hear that your code was working and then stopped. That would indicate a regression test problem. Does your code still work on demo?

Comment: I will do some more investigation and see if I can get these answer to you.